# Able to input name for the first object alone

Tags: java, arrays, class, object

```
for(i=0;i<5;i++)
{
    System.out.println("Enter name for student"+i);
    stud[i].name=v.nextLine();
    System.out.println("Enter number of the student"+i);
    stud[i].regno=v.nextInt();
}
```

v is the scanner object. I am able to input name for only the 1st object in the array of object. when the loop accesses second object it directly asks me for the regno, not for the name!

Answer (score 1):

Change to

```
System.out.println("Enter name for student"+i);
stud[i].name=v.next();
```

Comment: Wow! thank u so much! but btw what was the effect of changing v.nextLine to v.next? i mean...v.nextLine is meant for strings right?

Comment: @KumaravelRajan I have a dded an explanation of the behavior in my response

Comment: sincerely appreciate!